# To change from something to something / wechseln/umwechseln

Tags: difference, preposition, verb

If I want to change a Versandservice from one to another, do I use wechseln? And with which preposition?

Ich möchte den Versandservice von Economy auf/in/zu (oder irgendandere Präposition) Priority wechseln/umwechseln.
Oder wenn es um die Adresse geht, dann " Ich möchte meine Adresse im System von "...Straße 11.." an/zu/auf "...Straße 14" wechseln/umwechseln

Kann auch "tauschen" in diesen Fällen angewendet werden?

welche wäre die richtige Anwendung in diesem Fall?

Answer (score 1):

Die Vorsilbe von *um*-wechseln betont zwar den Wechsel, ändert die Bedeutung aber nicht wesentlich; ich würde *wechseln* im Zweifelsfall vorziehen. *Tauschen* ist in vielen Fällen mit physikalischen Gegenständen verbunden (z. B. beim Umtausch eines Einkaufs oder der der Ersatz einer Farbpatrone) und in den genannten Zusammenhängen wenig gebräuchlich.

In Deinen Beispielen ist aber auch *wechseln* keine besonders gut passende Formulierung:

Bei der Versandart tendiere ich zu *ich möchte die Versandart ändern*, bei der Adresse entweder zu *korrigieren* (wenn ein Fehler vorlag) oder *aktualisieren* (nach einem Umzug).

Comment: Und welche Präposition soll ich mit "ändern" bevorzugen? in dem Zusammenhang von "from...to...(smth)"

Comment: gar keine. Der Name wird geändert von X zu Y. Oder geändert (von X) in Y.